# How to parse a django template and render specific tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is it possible to parse a django template and only render a specific tag ?
This [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/942/) is close to what I'm looking for but it doesn't return the entire template.
Basically if I have this template as input

```
<html>
<title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% mycustomtag "args" %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

and i want to only render `mycustomtag` this is the output Im looking for

```
<html>
<title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>
<body>
{% block content %}
<p>Result from mycustomtag</p>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just parse the template all at once? Template parsing is not cheap.

Comment: Im generating a template from this template, and want to keep all tags the same except for "mycustomtag" :)

Comment: Is it feasible to do it manually? I.e., view the HTML of a page, copy the output of mycustomtag and paste it in (a copy of) the Django template?

Comment: Too cumbersome for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I properly understand your question, then there is a way to do that, using the `{% verbatim %}` tag. It will be [added in Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#verbatim-template-tag), but for now you can use it as your custom tag - here is the source: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16318

The only drawback here is that you cannot use directly this template, it needs double rendering. If this is what you need - then everything is OK.

To use it, all you need to do is to enclose the other tags with {% verbatim %} :

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}  <-- this is needed to load the 'verbatim' and 'mycustomtag' tags
{% verbatim %}
<html>
<title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endverbatim %}

{% mycustomtag "args" %}

{% verbatim %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
{% endverbatim %}
```

I've made a simple test with this template:

```
@register.simple_tag
def mycustomtag(a):
    return "<p>%s</p>" % a

....

from django.template import loader, Context
print loader.get_template("test.html").render(Context({}))
```

This prints the following:

```
<html>
<title>{%block title%}{%endblock%}</title>
<body>
{%block content%}

<p>args</p>

{%endblock content%}
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: I have used the code for the tag i found here https://gist.github.com/1313862 , unfortunately the {% block %} tags are still being rendered. Did this work for you ? If so which Django version ?

Comment: Do you try to render the template as a normal template ? Then the blocks will not be rendered. They will be rendered if processed again. I'm not quite sure what exactly is your goal. There is a way to render the template with and without the verbatim tags, but will require a little hack. Please explain how your code work, so I can help more.

Comment: I was rendering the wrong template :(. It works now, thanks :)